# Why is the scrollLeft function only working on the first click?

Tags: jquery

I want the `scrollLeft` function to scroll a div each time when I click a forward button

Code:

```
 $("#nextbutton").click(
  function()
  {
   $("#thumbholder").scrollLeft(300);
 });
```

Thumbholder holds the images and its `overflow:hidden`, I want to show the hidden items by scrolling to the left.

```
#thumbholder 
{
height:30%;
width:90%;
overflow: hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
margin:2% auto; 
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to repeat the scrollLeft function for each click on "#nextbutton", instead of just the first time I click it?

Comment: what do you really mean by repeat?

Comment: for every click on #thumbholder should scroll to left

Comment: @ismailvittal: I've edited the question to clarify.  Feel free to rollback my change if I missed the point of your question, and make further edits to clear things up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `scrollLeft` takes an absolute scrollbar position, not a relative one.

See [the docs for `scrollLeft`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/).

Try using `.scrollLeft()` to get the existing position, subtract 300 from it, and apply it back using the `.scrollButton(value)` function you're already using:

http://jsfiddle.net/RjWKp/

```
$("#leftButton").click(
    function() {
        var thumbHolder = $("#thumbholder");
        thumbHolder.scrollLeft(thumbHolder.scrollLeft() - 300);
    }
);
```

Comment: how can I add key press event to this ? while pressing left arrow and right arrow the same functionality should work.

Comment: @ismailvittal: That's a separate question, though you should look into  [the `.keydown()` function](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/), and try applying it to `$(window)`.  The `.keypress` function won't work because it only handles character keys, not special keys.  In your `.keydown` handler you can simply trigger your existing `$("#leftButton").click();` and `$("#leftButton").click();` handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#thumbholder")[0].scrollBy(-10, 0);` where the first parameter is the number of pixels to scroll horizontally (negative value will scroll it to the left, positive will scroll it to the right) and the second parameter is the number of pixels to scroll vertically. You can change the '10' in the above call as needed

Comment: Where is this `scrollBy` function declared?  I didn't see it in the jQuery docs, and it didn't seem to work when I tried it in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RjWKp/2/

Comment: `scrollBy()` is a DOM function. Not a jQuery function. It is available for DOM elements, thats why we call it with `$("#thumbholder")[0]` (notice the `[0]` at the end, it gives us the underlying DOM object)

Comment: It still isn't working.  Check out that fiddle.  Am I using it incorrectly?